# How to use Master Theorem with strange format of $b$ parameter?

Tags: asymptotics, recursion, master-theorem

I have a funcion $T: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined as:

$$T(n)=\begin{cases}
6 &\text{ if } n=0,\\
T(n-1) + 6n + 6 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

How can I apply the Master Theorem to this problem? I have only seen the M.T. in one of these two formats:

$$T(n) = aT(n/b) + f (n)$$
$$T(n) = aT(n/b) + \Theta(n^c)$$

So I'm wondering how to transform the $T(n-1)$ to something usable. Is it even possible to apply the theorem to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 4):

Not every recurrence falls within the bounds on the master theorem. Your recurrence is an example. However, by unrolling your recurrence, we can come up with an explicit formula:
$$
T(n) = 6(n+1) + T(n-1) = 6(n+1) + 6n + T(n-2) = \cdots = \\
6(n+1) + 6n + \cdots + 6\cdot 2 + T(0) = \\
6(n+1) + 6n + \cdots + 6\cdot 2 + 6\cdot 1 = \\
6 \sum_{m=1}^{n+1} m = 6\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2} = 3(n+2)(n+1).
$$

Answer (score 0):

The master theorem simply doesn't apply in this case. There is no constant $b$ such that $n-1=n/b$ for all $n$.  You must use [some other technique](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2789/9550) to solve the recurrence.